# Trying to use (make) with math.h

Tags: gcc

With gcc command I use the -lm flag with math.h. I trying to use make and I'm getting errors. Is there an lm trick with make and makefiles?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant section of your makefile, and the specific error(s) you get

Comment: `/usr/include/math.h` is the file, and it is part of the `libc6-dev` package for your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to `make` and you can compile your code manually on the command line, then I recommend the following steps:

1. Create a Makefile which basically does exactly what you would do on the command line, e.g.,

   `mybinary: mysourcecode.c
        gcc -o mybinary -lm mysourcecode.c`
2. Split up compiling and linking your code, e.g.,

   `mybinary: mysourcecode.o
        ld -o mybinary -lm mysourcecode.o
   mysourcode.o: mysourcecode.c
        gcc -c -o mysourcecode.o mysourcecode.c`
3. Make general rules and add use all the fancy features of `make`, e.g.,

`.PHONY: clean
objects := $(subst .c,.o,$(wildcard *.c))`

target  := mybinary

$(target): $(objects)
         ld -o $@ -lm $^
%.o: %.c
         gcc -c -o $@ $<
clean:
         -rm $(target) $(objects)